# Activerecords association with custom name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm learning Rails.

I'm trying to handle data from an existing mysql database with table's name that doesn't follow the Rails convention naming.

I have two classes

```
Class Articles
end
```

and

```
Class Category
end
```

Every article has one category, but I have this db schema

**Article table**

```
id
title
channel
```

**Category table**

```
id
name
```

In the "channel" filed of my article table I have the category ID.

I try with

```
Class Articles
has_one :category, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: 'channel'
end
```

It doesn't work! Why?

Comment: What exact error message do you get?  Are you sure you posted your exact code?  In ruby, the class keyword is lower case and your class should inherit from ActiveRecord::Base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_one` means the foreign key is on the other table. In your case you should be using `belongs_to` in your Article class, since your articles table contains the category foreign key.